# How can I put queried data (via post) on my jquery chart?

Tags: javascript, jquery, chart.js

I am using mdb bootstrap to display data saved in my database. The problem that I am having is that when I use `$.post` My pie chart disappears. The error in the console is `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier` and this comes up on the line `var hold = 1;` I am not familiar with javascript and can't see my error here. Here is my code:

```
<!-- Charts -->
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    //pie
    var ctxP = document.getElementById("pieChart").getContext('2d');
    var myPieChart = new Chart(ctxP, {

           var hold = 1;
           var data_String;
           data_String = 'hold='+hold
           $.post('fetch/ft-invoice-breakdown.php',data_String,function(data){
                 var data = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
              });


        type: 'doughnut',
        data: {
            labels:['Pending', 'Approved', 'Paid', 'Blocked', 'Cancelled'],
            datasets: [
                {
                    data: [9, 6, 4, 1, 0],
                    backgroundColor: ["#F7464A", "#46BFBD", "#FDB45C", "#949FB1", "#4D5360"],
                    hoverBackgroundColor: ["#FF5A5E", "#5AD3D1", "#FFC870", "#A8B3C5", "#616774"]
                }
            ]
        },
        options: {
            responsive: true
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

I also need to replace `data: [9, 6, 4, 1, 0]` with the values that I query in my post. Would doing this just be `data: data`? I've done many searches and can't find any examples of setting this chart up with a db. This chart is provided by material bootstrap (mdb)

**UPDATE: Post is now working**

But my problem remains that I can't put `chartData` (which i swapped with `data`) in for the dataset of my chart. I've tried making `chartData` a global variable but it still is not recognized in my Chart object.

```
<!-- Charts -->
<script>
var chartData
$(document).ready(function(){

  $.ajax({
    url: '../fetch/ft-invoice-breakdown.php',
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(msg){
      var chartData = msg;
    }
  });
  alert(chartData);

    //pie
    var ctxP = document.getElementById("pieChart").getContext('2d');
    var myPieChart = new Chart(ctxP, {

        type: 'doughnut',
        data: {
            labels:['Pending', 'Approved', 'Paid', 'Blocked', 'Cancelled'],
            datasets: [
                {
                    data: chartData,
                    backgroundColor: ["#F7464A", "#46BFBD", "#FDB45C", "#949FB1", "#4D5360"],
                    hoverBackgroundColor: ["#FF5A5E", "#5AD3D1", "#FFC870", "#A8B3C5", "#616774"]
                }
            ]
        },
        options: {
            responsive: true
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

my `alert(chartData);` prints `undefined`.

**UPDATE 2: Response from PHP 'post' is `[1,5,8,0,0]`**

Comment: you need to 1st ajax call outside the object and store data inside the object. then call a function that has parameter as the data and initializes it...

Comment: put all the code inside a function and pass the ajax data object as argument and place it in the property...

Comment: @AneesIjaz how do I convert the object to array after?

Comment: `$.ajax` is an async task. You should move your code alert() to `success:` or `await` the result

Comment: @MadhanVaradhodiyil I'm only using `alert()` here as a way to debug. Seeing if I can access the variable `chartData` outside of the ajax request.

Comment: alert and ajax will execute at same time. [ async methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)

Comment: @MadhanVaradhodiyil okay I see what you are saying now. Is there a way I can access `chartData` and redraw the table after the variable is defined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `$ajax` requests are sent [asynchronously](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/), unless you set `async:false` , I think you need to drawChart once you get an response.

Something like :

```
function drawChart(chartData){
    //pie
    var ctxP = document.getElementById("pieChart").getContext('2d');
    var myPieChart = new Chart(ctxP, {

        type: 'doughnut',
        data: {
            labels:['Pending', 'Approved', 'Paid', 'Blocked', 'Cancelled'],
            datasets: [
                {
                    data: chartData,
                    backgroundColor: ["#F7464A", "#46BFBD", "#FDB45C", "#949FB1", "#4D5360"],
                    hoverBackgroundColor: ["#FF5A5E", "#5AD3D1", "#FFC870", "#A8B3C5", "#616774"]
                }
            ]
        },
        options: {
            responsive: true
        }
    });
}
$(document).ready(function(){

    $.ajax({
    url: '../fetch/ft-invoice-breakdown.php',
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(msg){
        drawChart(msg);  //Call this method on successful data retrieval with msg as parameter 
    }
    });


});
```

Comment: This seems to almost get it. But i get `mdb.min.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: Object.defineProperty called on non-object` right now

Comment: Is the response from php a `JSON` Can you post sample data please?

Comment: The response is an array `[1,5,8,0,0]`. No json, this is my bad I should have updated this in my post

Comment: Not quite sure why you're getting that error ! Here is an plunkr demo  : https://plnkr.co/edit/8o4myNmXNKjA59FXSn74?p=preview

Comment: Does it have to do with the code not being enclosed in `<head>` tags?

Comment: Nope. I don't think it'll cause any troubles . Are you getting [this error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51792120/how-can-i-put-queried-data-via-post-on-my-jquery-chart/51793059?noredirect=1#comment90543722_51793059) after the cart is loaded?

Comment: When I load up your exact code into a new page (using my url) [These are the errors I get](https://imgur.com/uB7WdNE)

Comment: Are there any other components which might induce the error?

Comment: I have all the same dependencies you have. Can I see your `data.json` file? I json encode my array but it doesn't look like its in json format. From my errors it doesn't seem to be recognizing my data as an object

Comment: It's there in that plnkr editor. It looks something like `[1,5,8,0,0]` . (A json array of numbers) .

Comment: Ok its definitely a problem with my output. I made my own json file and it works perfectly. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Ah! . No worries . I'm glad I was of any help!